# I want to insert item meta in in order through rest API in WooCommerce

Tags: php, arrays, json, wordpress, woocommerce-rest-api

I created one text field through WC Field Factory with the name of "Camper Name"

Showing in [this product](http://campstore.myworkdemo.com/product/woo-album-2/)

Now the problem is when I'm filling this field from frontend and placing order this field show in Woocommerce Order API when I'm retrieving data but when I'm trying to insert meta through creating Order API then not going in order and when I'm retrieving order show "meta"[] empty. Can anyone help to resolve this issue?

Here I'm try to create order through POSTMAN

```
{

 "payment_method": "cod",
    "payment_method_title": "Direct Bank Transfer",
    "set_paid": true,
    "billing": {
      "first_name": "Ram",
      "last_name": "Kumar",
      "address_1": "969 Market",
      "address_2": "",
      "city": "Vsp",
      "state": "AP",
      "postcode": "530016",
      "country": "India",
      "email": "ramkumar@example.com",
      "phone": "(986) 444-5555"
    },
    "shipping": {
      "first_name": "Ram",
      "last_name": "Kumar",
      "address_1": "969 Market",
      "address_2": "",
      "city": "Vsp",
      "state": "AP",
      "postcode": "530016",
      "country": "India"
    },
    "line_items": [
      {
        "product_id": 938,
        "quantity": 1,
        "meta": [
          {
            "key": "Camper Name",
            "label":"Camper Name",
            "value":"furqan fazlani"
          }
        ]
      },
       {
        "product_id": 262,
        "quantity": 5
      }
    ],
    "shipping_lines": [
      {
        "method_id": "flat_rate",
        "method_title": "Flat Rate",
        "total": 2
      }
    ]
}
```

Comment: can you please write down your code what you are trying for this

Comment: Thanks For your reply!#navnit mishra I added JSON code Please check and reply please

Comment: Ive been wanting to do the same, but I dont think its plausible with the current rest version (v1). It's still in its infancy.

Comment: Tune in here: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/13569